# iPad UIViewController best practice for complicated interfaces

Tags: ios, ipad, layout, uiviewcontroller

I would like to develop an application for iPad, using a layout like that shown in this link:

https://skitch.com/sparkoletto/g13ck/ipad-views-layout

As you can see in the image on one page I would like to insert a UITableView (B), two UIScrollView (one vertical (D) and one horizontal (A)) and a simple UIView (C).

What is the best way to develop such interfaces?

It 'best to use a single ViewController that manages all the views that I need, or create a ViewController for each view, and then combine them all together in another UIViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with @TomSwift. When these things get complicated, it's very helpful to break them out into their own view controllers. You'll create a view controller of the correct type and then `[self.view addSubview:vc.view]` at some point.

The problem with making one complicated view controller is that it becomes delegate and datasource for too many things that are internal details of individual subviews. Your delegate methods now need to check which tableview is talking to them, for instance.

Splitting them up also makes it much easier to manage rotation, particularly if you want a different set of views displayed in each orientation. This is good for memory management as well, since the VCs can automatically unload the views you aren't using anymore.

Breaking things up too small is of course also a problem. There is a cost to having separate view controllers, especially if they interact with each other. Having a good feel for when is the right time is the mark of an experienced developer. But for the view you showed, I would almost certainly break it up. Your situation looks very much like `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why did you say _"Splitting them up also makes it much easier to manage rotation, particularly if you want a different set of views displayed in each orientation."_ ?In this case how it would be handled the rotation of each views?

Comment: The point here is the case where you want to hide some views in portrait or landscape (for instance your side scroller). With separate view controllers, you can let your master view controller drop (nil) the entire subview and its view controller. Then when you rotate back, you can recreate it. With a separate nib file, this is pretty easy. If everything is in one nib file, then you have to do a lot of coding by hand to get the same benefit.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested because I think is the best way, but when the interface rotates, some methods such as `-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` are only called in the MasterViewController and not in the others. It's normal? In this case, if I have to resize the subviews of the other ViewController whenever the interface rotates from landscape to portrait and viceversa, I have to call a method for each child UIViewController to resize their views?

Comment: This is correct. You'll need to pass through the view controller event messages to your children view controllers. You usually just do this by storing your children vcs in an array, and looping over it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a single view controller, IMO, unless you plan to reuse some of these panes in other places.  In which case you could implement a "container view controller" with a single view to handle the layout of the child view controllers.

Typically view controllers manage "full screen" (or nearly full screen) views.  The exceptions are fairly rare - UISplitViewController is one.